# Displaying nodes sorted by distance to a given node in Python

Tags: python, function, sorting, nodes

I have a number of nodes, each has an x-axis and y-axis values which indicate a distance from each other. For example,

```
nodes = [
{'name': 'node1', 'x': 2, 'y': 4, 'friend': True},
{'name': 'node2', 'x': -3, 'y': 2, 'friend': True},
{'name': 'node3', 'x': 5, 'y': 0, 'friend': False},
{'name': 'node4', 'x': -6, 'y': 1, 'friend': False},
{'name': 'node5', 'x': 0, 'y': 3, 'friend': True} 
]
```

I need to create a function that returns only nodes who are friends sorted by a distance to a given node (say `main_node = nodes[0]`) based on the X and Y values.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Please clarify the "distance." Is this Cartesian distance in two dimensions, sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2) ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It is a Cartesian distance based on two dimensions.

Comment: Also, I would like to consider a case with a Euclidean distance.

Comment: What is the difference between Cartesian and Euclidean distance? I use those terms to mean the same thing. There are other distances such as the taxicab metric.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I mixed up between the two.

Answer (score 0):

The sort function takes a key parameter:

```
main_node = nodes[0]
nodes.sort(key=lambda node: math.hypot(node["x"] - main_node["x"], node["y"] - main_node["y"]))
```

Comment: Thanks Francisco. Is there anything needs to be imported, please?

Comment: Yes, the `math` module, `import math`. Of course you could use the formula you used instead

Comment: Francisco, could you please revise the line of code as it gives me an invalid syntax error.

Comment: Pretty sure it works, tried with both Python 2 and 3, make sure to import math and that you're copying the whole line.

Comment: import random
import math

nodes = [
 { 'name': 'node1', 'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'friend': True },
 { 'name': 'node2', 'x': 3, 'y': 4, 'friend': False },
 { 'name': 'node3', 'x': -5, 'y': -1, 'friend': True },
 { 'name': 'node4', 'x': 2, 'y': 7, 'friend': True },
 { 'name': 'node5', 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'friend': False }
]

main_node = nodes[0]
friend_nodes = [node for node in nodes if node['friend'] == True]

print('friends nodes: ' + str(friend_nodes))
output= nodes.sort(key=lambda node: math.hypot(node['x'] - main_node['x'], node['y'] - main_node['y']))
print(output)

Comment: I guess what you meant is that `output` is `None`, that's because `sort` sorts in place, if you want a new list use `sorted`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125845/discussion-between-s-slade-and-francisco-couzo).